# Block npm from installing some packages

Tags: security, npm

Is there a way to block npm from installing some packages (i.e. `node-ipc`, `peacenotwar`, `node-http-server` and other alike), even if they are dependencies to other installed ones?

The block shall be applied to whole dependency tree, not only to first level (my own package.json).

Comment: Use your own registry that doesn't include those packages?

Comment: Well, own registry or some proxy that just prohibits access to sources URL of specified packages should be a good solution for enterprise. But I need some simple solution for home open-source development.

Comment: In that case: no. You could script a check of the `package-lock.json` to find out when you've installed something you didn't want to.

Comment: Good idea, but some kind of pre-action check (that displays why some package can't be installed) would be much better.

Comment: That way you'd only be checking the top-level package being installed, not any transitive dependencies.